# How to determine type parameter's variance?

Tags: scala, types, covariance, contravariance, generic-variance

Inspired by [Real-world examples of co- and contravariance in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277526/real-world-examples-of-co-and-contravariance-in-scala) I thought a better question would be:

When designing a library, are there a specific set of questions you should ask yourself when determining whether a type parameter should be covariant or contravariant?  Or should you make everything invariant and then change as needed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, simple, does it make sense? Think of Liskov substitution.

### Co-variance

If `A <: B`, does it make sense to pass a `C[A]` where a `C[B]` is expected? If so, make it `C[+T]`. The classic example is the immutable `List`, where a `List[A]` can be passed to anything expecting a `List[B]`, assuming `A` is a subtype of `B`.

Two counter examples:

Mutable sequences are invariant, because it is possible to have type safety violations otherwise (in fact, Java's co-variant `Array` is vulnerable to just such things, which is why it is invariant in Scala).

Immutable `Set` is invariant, even though its methods are very similar to those of an immutable `Seq`. The difference lies with `contains`, which is typed on sets and untyped (ie, accept `Any`) on sequences. So, even though it would otherwise be possible to make it co-variant, the desire for an increased type safety on a particular method led to a choice of invariance over co-variance.

### Contra-variance

If `A <: B`, does it make sense to pass a `C[B]` where a `C[A]` is expected? If so, make it `C[-T]`. The classic would-be example is `Ordering`. While some unrelated technical problems prevent `Ordering` from being contra-variant, it is intuitive that anything that can order a super-class of `A` can also order `A`. It follows that `Ordering[B]`, which orders all elements of type `B`, a supertype of `A`, can be passed to something expecting an `Ordering[A]`.

While Scala's `Ordering` is not contra-variant, [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/)'s [Order](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/Order.scala.html) is contra-variant as expected. Another example from Scalaz is its [Equal](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/Equal.scala.html) trait.

### Mixed Variance?

The most visible example of mixed variance in Scala is `Function1` (and 2, 3, etc). It is contra-variant in the parameter it receives, and co-variant in what it returns. Note, though, that `Function1` is what is used for a lot of closures, and closures are used in a lot of places, and these places are usually where Java uses (or would use) Single Abstract Method classes.

So, if you have a situation where a SAM class applies, that's likely a place for mixed contra-variance and co-variance.